# How to make my method to wait for button click event in winforms

Tags: c#, json, winforms, treeview

I have winForms project , my button_click 1 is add in elements of my one of documents chapters and sections. I want to save my configurations in configurations file test.json (it is written by JSON format) . I am saving everything what is chosen by checking check boxes. And later I want to load what check boxes are checked. But how to wait till `button_click1` event will be clicked and my check boxes will appear. My load files looks like:

```
 private void SaveConfig(string path)
        {
            var config = new DocConfig();
            config.Parts = new List<DocPart>();


            foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
            {

                {
                    config.Parts.Add(new DocPart { NodeTitle = node.Text, NodeChecked = node.Checked });
                }


                    {
                        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
                        {
                            config.Parts.Add(new DocPart { ChildTitle = child.Text, ChildChecked = child.Checked });
                        }
                    }


                var configString = config.SaveToString();
                File.WriteAllText(path, configString);

            }
        }
        private void LoadConfig(string path)
        {

            var cfgString = File.ReadAllText(path);
            var cfg = DocConfig.LoadFromString(cfgString);


            foreach (var part in cfg.Parts)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    if (part.NodeTitle == "chap1")
                    {
                        node.Checked = part.NodeChecked;
                    }
                    if (part.NodeTitle == "chap2")
                    {
                        node.Checked = part.NodeChecked;
                    }
                    if (part.NodeTitle == "chap3")
                    {
                        node.Checked = part.NodeChecked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removed button1_click() and added this class

```
private void Initializetreeview();

    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("chapter1") { Tag = @"\include {chapter1}" }); ;
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("chapter2") { Tag = @"\include {chapter2}" });
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("chapter3") { Tag = @"\include {chapter3}" });

    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("section1") { Tag = @"\input {sec1}" });
                treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("section2") { Tag = @"\input {sec2}" });
                treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("section3") { Tag = @"\input {sec3}" });
```

Removing from added list button2_Click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveChecked(treeView1.Nodes);
        }

        void RemoveChecked(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in FindCheckedNodes(nodes))
            {
                nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
            }
        }


        private List<TreeNode> FindCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    checkedNodes.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    // find checked childs        
                    checkedNodes.AddRange(FindCheckedNodes(node.Nodes));
                }
            }
            return checkedNodes;
        }
```

Here is my load event handler, where I call my LoadConfig:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Initializetreeview();
            var cmdArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            if (cmdArgs.Length == 1)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("None file loaded as parameter");
            }
            if (cmdArgs.Length == 2)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("JSON file is not loaded as parameter");
                var dconfFilename = cmdArgs[1];
                LoadConfig(dconfFilename);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Move the code to the click event? It's not clear what you mean...

Comment: I want to make document configuration file save and load using check boxes settings. So I am saving my check boxes, but when I want to use them like command line parameters, I need to wait till my button1_click event is clicked. Then I open every check box and using document config I want to check my check boxes, which are set to be checked.

Comment: Then as I said, move the code to your click event.

Comment: Also posting all the code would be a lot more helpful if someone tries to help you

Comment: All the code is more than 400lines :/ I am just looking for ideas.

Comment: The code referent to saving/loading.

Comment: added saving and loading methods. DocConfig is my class for JSON format, DocParts is my class for getting values of Titles and Checkstatus. First I am trying to load just Nodes.

Comment: You didn't show your key method/eventhandler `button1_Click`? What code is inside it. Or put your `LoadConfig` method in the `Form.Load` eventhandler

Comment: button1_click is just `treeview1.Nodes.add(text)`and  `treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes(text)` . I wil try to move LoadConfig

Comment: @Fabio still nothing good happens. My winForm load and I need to click button first and only then my check box options appears. In this case my document configuration stays unloaded.

Comment: Show your `button_click` code

Comment: @Fabio I added button_click events 1 and 2.

Comment: Move code from `button1_click` to the `Form.Load` eventhandler - before `LoadConfig` method or in the constructor of the form

Comment: When and how is `button1_Click()` called? When and how is `LoadConfig()` called? In what way _specifically_ are these two methods related? Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Explain precisely what that code does, and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterDuniho button1_click is called when I launch my winform application window. LoadConfig() is called with my load.form event handler. I want throught command line to type `c:\dir\treeview.exe test.json` and then I should add my nodes and children to a check box list and test.json should check check boxes which is written in Json. But in my case, first of all winforms open empty window and only then I click button1 to generate all check box list, so my test.json isn't doing anything.

Comment: @Fabio If I understood right, you offer me to remove my button1_click() event and move that event code, to event holder? I will edit my post and add event holder of load.form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `LoadConfig` method assume that `TreeView` control already has nodes with names, you need initialize TreeView before executing `LoadConfig` method

```
//Create method which initialize treeview control with your nodes
private void InitializeTreeView()
{
    this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("chapter1") { Tag = @"\include {chapter1}" });
    this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("chapter2") { Tag = @"\include {chapter2}" });
    this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("chapter3") { Tag = @"\include {chapter3}" });

    this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("section1") { Tag = @"\input {sec1}" });
    this.treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("section2") { Tag = @"\input {sec2}" });
    this.treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("section3") { Tag = @"\input {sec3}" });
}

private void Form_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.InitializeTreeView();

    //Now you can load your config
    var cmdArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    if (cmdArgs.Length == 1)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("None file loaded as parameter");
    }
    if (cmdArgs.Length == 2)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("JSON file is not loaded as parameter");
        var dconfFilename = cmdArgs[1];
        LoadConfig(dconfFilename);
    }
}
```

Comment: should I leave my button1_click() as it is now?

Comment: You don't need this anymore, because TreeView will be filled with nodes already in the Load eventhandler, which executed once before form shown

Comment: Yep, thanks for this tip. But still I need to continue my research, because it's not working :) I will accept your answer, but maybe you can give some hints what could not work right in my program?

Comment: Show your *current* code(update question), tell what you expecting, add Error message or Exception and line where it is happened if happened.

Comment: I removed my button1_click() event. Now I want to load my json file. save methond is saving everything. But load method isn't giving anything to my check boxes.

Comment: it is saying that I am using json files as arg[1] in command line, but it is not loading my check boxes status.